# Selenium Python Chrome unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist In Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I cannot resolve this error, I tried everything that was suggested to start chrome webdriver with my current profile

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pathlib import Path
import time

# initialize the Chrome driver
_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
print(str(Path.home())+"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/dmitr/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
#_options.add_argument("--headless")


s = Service('D:\chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=_options)
```

I dont have anything else I can try, why is this not working?

Comment: What do you get when executing `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory=Default --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your editor w/ admin permissions?  When I ran your code, it failed too until I opened VSCode as an admin, then it worked.  I'm using ChromeDriver version 111.0.5563.64